# GPIO Button press runs the print method more than one time

Tags: button, raspberry-pi, state, gpio

GPIO Button State reading using raspberry pi 3
    ----------------------------------------------

Question : when I run the code below and press on the button attached to my pi **only once**, it prints the "The button has been pressed" more than one time (sometimes , it can print it 100 times)

**Does anyone know why this happens?**
   Thanks in advance for your cooperation

```
-----
code:
-----
 buttonPin = 17
    import RPi.GPIO as gpio
    gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
    gpio.setup(buttonPin, gpio.IN)
    count=0
    ButtonState=True    #means that the button is in the up position and has not yet been pressed.

    while True:
        input_value = gpio.input(17)
        if input_value == False:
            print('The button has been pressed...')
            print(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to add a delay after the print(). Your script is moving too quickly and the switch is still pressed after the first iteration.

Easy fix:

```
buttonPin = 17
import RPi.GPIO as gpio

#Import time library for delays
import time

gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(buttonPin, gpio.IN)
count=0
ButtonState=True    #means that the button is in the up position and has not yet been pressed.

while True:
    input_value = gpio.input(17)
    if input_value == False:
        print('The button has been pressed...')
        print(count)

        #Add a debounce delay "time.sleep(duration)"
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

This means your script will not continue until 0.5 seconds after the button press, giving time for the button to be released.